if f is a continuous function such that $\int_1^8 f(x) \,dx= 9$, then $\int_1^2 t^2f(t) \,dt$
The answers are:

=9
=3
=27
Provided data is not enough

I think it can be solved integrating by parts, but i dont find the correct way of doing it.
Thanks in advance!!

Is the integrand meant to be $t^2f(t^3)$? If not, the answer is not enough info.

Should the integration areas really change? Otherwise, choose any continuous function that is constant 0 on $[1,2]$. Then the second integral is 0, but the first can be any real number, in particular 9.

I suspect this question wants to know $\int_1^2 t^2 f(t^3) dt$ instead of $\int_1^2 t^2 f(t) dt$, which gives an answer of "provided data is not enough" (take $f(x)=\frac{9}{7}$ and $f(x)=\frac{2}{7}x$).
Anyway, if I suspect right, then we can use the substitution $x=t^3$. This gives $dx=3t^2dt$ and our bounds become $x=1$ and $x=8$.
Thus $\int_1^2 t^2 f(t^3)dt = \frac{1}{3} \int_1^2 3t^2f(t^3)dt=\frac{1}{3}\int_1^8 f(x)dx = \frac{1}{3}(9)=3.$

Thank you very much!! yeah, it can be wrong I will ask my professor also but I have a math class tomorrow.
